# Count the number of clients that have bought in different stores in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| client | product | store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | toy1 | 10 |
| 001 | toy2 | 20 |
| 003 | toy3 | 10 |
| 004 | toy4 | 40 |
| 001 | toy4 | 30 |
| 004 | toy4 | 50 |

What I need to do it´s to count the number of clients that have bought in one store, two stores, three stores and more, something like this.

| one store | two stores | three stores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

The purpose of this I´ts to count how many clients buy in different stores, It´s there anyway to this with python?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_df = df.groupby('client')['store'].count().value_counts().to_frame().sort_index().T.add_suffix(' store').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   1 store  2 store  3 store
0        1        1        1
```

Comment: Just one question what does the T.add_sufix does, sorry Im kind of new on this

Comment: `.T` transposes the dataframe - it makes the column headers be the row labels and the row labels be the column headers. `.add_suffix` adds the specified suffix to the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
output = (df.groupby("client")["store"]
            .nunique()
            .reset_index()
            .groupby("store")
            .count()
            .T
            .add_suffix(" store")
            .rename_axis(None,axis=1))

>>> output
        1 store  2 store  3 store
client        1        1        1
```